# How to get audio track for Visualizer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio-player

I'm attempting to create a audio visualizer that will pulse based on the audio that is being played. I've created a 3D model using three.js that currently pulses randomly, but I'm having trouble understanding how to get the audio file itself.

I'm using [this repo](https://github.com/philnash/react-web-audio/tree/master/src) as a hint, but I'm stuck at the App.js file. The purpose of this code is to get input from the user via a microphone and I'm having trouble understanding the WebAPI docs for getting an audio file instead.

How do I point the app to get audio from a file instead of the microphone?

EDIT:

audio.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AudioAnalyser from './audioAnalyser';

import song from './Teehee.mp3';

class Audio extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        audioStatus: 'PAUSED'
    };
    this.audioEle = null;
    this.songName = 'Blues in A';
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.audioEle = document.getElementById('audio-element');
    this.audioEle.oncanplay = (e) => {
      // safari
      if (this.isSafari()) {
        return
      }
      this.play()
    }
  }

  isSafari = () => {
    return window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') > -1 && window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') === -1
  }

  pause = () => {
    this.audioEle.pause()
    this.setState({
      audioStatus: 'PAUSED'
    })
  }
  play = () => {
    this.audioEle.play()
    this.setState({
      audioStatus: 'PLAYING'
    })
    console.log(this.state);

  }

  toggleMusic = () =>  {

    console.log(this.state);

    if (this.state.audioStatus === 'PLAYING') {
      this.pause();
    } else {
      this.play();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="AudioPlayer">        
        <audio id="audio-element" preload="true" src={`${song}`} crossorigin="anonymous" ></audio>
        <div className="controls">
          <button onClick={this.toggleMusic}>
            {this.state.audioStatus ? 'PAUSED' : 'PLAYING'}
          </button>
        </div>
        {this.state.audioStatus ? <AudioAnalyser audio={this.state.audioStatus} /> : ''}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Audio;
```

audioAnalyser.js

```
/*
This component will analyse an audio file using the Web Audio API, more information can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

https://www.twilio.com/blog/audio-visualisation-web-audio-api--react

*/

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AudioVisualiser from './audioVisualizer';

class AudioAnalyser extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { audioData: new Uint8Array(0) };
        this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
      }


    // When Component mounts, set up Web Autio API objets.
    componentDidMount() {

        // The AudioContext interface represents an audio-processing graph built from audio modules linked together, each represented by an AudioNode.
        this.audioContext = new (window.AudioContext ||  window.webkitAudioContext)();

        // The AnalyserNode interface represents a node able to provide real-time frequency and time-domain analysis information.
        this.analyser = this.audioContext.createAnalyser();

        // This dataArray will be used to store the waveform data that the AnalyserNode will be creating.
        this.dataArray = new Uint8Array(this.analyser.frequencyBinCount);


        console.log(this.props);

        console.log(this.props.audio);
        // The source, which is the audio file.
        this.source = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(this.props.audio);

        // connect source to the anlayser .
        this.source.connect(this.analyser);
      }

      // Method that will be called every time requestAnimationFrame runs. 
      // The function will copy the current waveform as an array of integers, from the AnalyserNode into the dataArray. 
      // It will then update the audioData property in the component's state with the dataArray. 
      // Finally, it will call on requestAnimationFrame again to request the next update.
      tick() {

        // Use the analyser to update the visualization from the dataArray
        this.analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(this.dataArray);

        // 
        this.setState({ audioData: this.dataArray });

        this.rafId = requestAnimationFrame(this.tick);


      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.rafId);
        this.analyser.disconnect();
        this.source.disconnect();
      }

      render() {
        return <AudioVisualiser audioData={this.state.audioData} />;
      }
    }

    export default AudioAnalyser;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [input element with type file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) and then use the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications) to access the the audio file and add it to the App's state.

Comment: I want the audio that I've defined to be played. I know I can use the `audio` tag to define audio files in HTML, but how do I get react to interact with it?

Comment: How was the audio you're using defined? Assuming it's defined somewhere you should be able to access it with the JavaScript File API and interact with it using React. Can you make a CodeSandbox illustrating the problem?

Comment: I've got the audio playing by embedding the mp3 in the HTML rendered by React. I'm now hitting a blocker where I'm attempting to create a `MediaStreamSource` but I'm unsure how I can pass the actual Source across files. If you take a look at my edited question, you can see where I pass the audio at the bottom of the first file.

Unfortunately, this passes the object which only contains the state and not the audio itself. I'm reading through the MDN docs right now to see if I can learn anything else.

Comment: I accidentally edited your answer, please ignore, thanks